# NavigateToStream. What URI (if any) is used for resolving relative links?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have an WPF application which uses a `<WebBrowser>` object to display some content which is in turn wrapped in HTML -- I want to generate that HTML on the fly, but it will hold links to different kinds of static content which will be local files.  In a normal web application, I would try to use relative URIs for this -- they will be looked up relative to the URI of the dynamic page.

The problem is if I use `WebBrowser.NavigateToStream` (or `.NavigateToString`).  In this case what is the "root" URI used for resolving relative links?  Can I control it?  Is it fixed?  Perhaps relative Uris are simply banned in such data streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding [`<base href="root_path">`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) into the `<head>` section of the generated page. It works with `NavigateToString`, at least:

```
this.webBrowser.NavigateToString(
    @"<head><base href='file://C:\Users\User\Documents\'></head><body><img src='image.jpg'></body>");
```

Comment: If it works with `.NavigateToString` then I expect it will work with `.NavigateToStream`.  I will accept your answer once I get a chance to try it out.

Comment: **Nota bene**: The trailing backslash is signficant.  That sounds weird, but it makes sense when you think about how relative URLs usually work.  It still bit me.