# Is it possible to navigate with a webBroser object to an isolated storage folder in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

In a WPF Application got a WebBrowser and I want it to navigate using a isolated storage file as source.

If I pass a relative path it will complain. I've also ried using "ms-appdata:" and "isostore:" to build the URI but nothing seems to work.

I can't use the NavigateToString as I need JS files to be run as well and they're also store on the isolated space.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Use the `<base>` tag: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21270840/1768303

Comment: How can this be done to load a index.html file in my isolated storage?

Comment: My idea was to try loading `index.html` as string then use `NavigateToString`. Have `<base href="ms-appdata:///local/">` in the `<head>` section of `index.html` (provided your JS files are in `local` folder). I haven't tried that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm afraid it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we've finally used is this piece of code:

```
    Uri url = new Uri("file:///" + rootdir + uri.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute);                    
    this.wbControl.Navigate(url);
```

where rootdir is got by the following method:

```
    public string GetRootDir()
    {
        Type type = isoStore.GetType();
        FieldInfo field = type.GetField("m_RootDir", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        string rootDir = field.GetValue(isoStore).ToString();
        return rootDir;
    }
```

But the main problem is that using file:/// does not allow to use html5 localstorage object...

Any other idea?